# Aspectj access parameter of the calling method and the return value of a called method

Tags: aspectj

I have to put some status data into the context object. This has to be done in lot of places so I thought it would be nice to solve this with AOP.
The problem is that I don't know how to access the callers parameter and the return value of the called method in the same advice. Is this possible at all?

```
public BusinessObject methodA(Context ctx, Param p) {
    Status s = service.serviceMethod(p);

    if (s.hasErrors()) 
    {
        ctx.put("error_key", s.getErrors());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give a example, to see if I correctlly understand your question